# Is OWL2 + SWRL math built ins decidable?

Tags: owl, swrl, decidable

I know that reasoning doesn't work in general when combining SWRL and OWL2 because the combination is not decidable. However, it is decidable when only certain things/rules are used. So assuming I only want to use the [SWRL math built-ins](https://www.w3.org/Submission/SWRL/#8.2), is decibability given or not?

Comment: no, because you could still use a non-simple role in the ontology in a rule that defines its transitivity, which is, among others, a clear indicator for undecidability in SROIQ